# Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

I am trying to start a Redux application I just cloned from a GitHub repository.

I tried to run it with the following command

```
npm start
```

I am getting this error

```
> react-redux@1.0.0 start /home/workspace/assignment
> webpack-dev-server --config ./configs/webpack/webpack.config.development.js

sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! react-redux@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --config ./configs/webpack/webpack.config.development.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2018-05-15T16_32_44_571Z-debug.log
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Every time I get an upvote on this question it reminds me of "how basic step it was". 
But again I was new with node and it knowing a lot of new devs need this (perhaps experienced ones too ;P) it feels good :D

Answer (score 266, accepted):

`npm start` runs a script that the app maker built for easy starting of the app
`npm install` installs all the packages in package.json

run `npm install` first

then run `npm start`

Comment: Tried this. Immediately get
 npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://<my-private-registry>/repository/npm-private/ts-acoustics
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

no node-module folder created and I am logged in.

Comment: your error is self explanatory. you have a package in your package.json that is not allowed due to your own security policy. Be careful about installing packages you find across the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same error message, but when I was running a package.json with:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p ./src",
}
```

`tsc` is the command to run the TypeScript compiler.

I never had any issues with this project because I had TypeScript installed as a global module. As this project didn't include TypeScript as a dev dependency (and expected it to be installed as global), I had the error when testing in another machine (without TypeScript) and running `npm install` didn't fix the problem. So I had to include TypeScript as a dev dependency (`npm install typescript --save-dev`) to solve the problem.

Comment: Adding TS as a dev dependency worked for me, thanks! I trigger a build with tsc in the postinstall script, so that my TS app builds and deploys properly on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also raise when you change your system password but not the same updated on your **.npmrc** file that exist on path **C:\Users\user_name**, so update your password there too.

please check on it and run npm install first and then npm start.

Answer (score -1):

Working in Grapesjs and get the same error

> goto package.json file and check dependencies

1. Removing unused plugins or unused libraries.
2. npm install
3. npm start

> Sometimes not useful install plugins get errors.

Answer (score -3):

Use [**`npm install`**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) to install the package.  I was having a permission issue with running this, due to the closed-nature of my office VPN.  This'll solve permission problems...

```
sudo npm install
```

In some cases with permissions, when this fails, it emits no error message.  In that case, you may want to adjust user permissions with either [**`chown`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) or [**`chmod`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).  Other times, though, when it fails, you'll actually see a legit error message...

> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400
>
> npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

Comment: Caution: Using sudo with package managers can get you into trouble. Fix the permissions instead.